# Recording canvas image to video file using recordrtc

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, recordrtc

I am trying to create some animation using canvas and saving it as a video file using [RecordRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/), this code works perfect, but I am having difficulties in getting the div with image to record.

```
<div style="display:none;" id="background_goa">
<img src="Http://domain/wp-content/themes/custom/images/top10-bg-goa.png'; ?>" />
</div>

function video_create(){
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 150, 150);            
  var img = document.getElementById("background_goa");
  ctx.drawImage(img,100,100);
  // ctx.restore();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(top_video_create);       
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(top_video_create);

var recorder = RecordRTC(canvas, {
  type: 'canvas'
});

recorder.startRecording();

setTimeout(function(){
recorder.stopRecording(function() {
  var blob = recorder.getBlob();
  document.body.innerHTML = '<video controls src="' + URL.createObjectURL(blob) + '" autoplay loop></video>';
 });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: The problem was ctx.restore(); now works like a charm. Thanks Mr. Khan.

Comment: Please add answer yourself to this page and mark as "solved". Regards

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was using ctx.restore(); basically what it does is restore the entire canvas after the draw, its supposed to be used before drawing the new element to canvas, so that the screen is blank before the next frame loads.